# Lambda expression to add objects from one list to another type of list

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-8

There is a `List<MyObject>` and it's objects are required to create object that will be added to another List with different elements : `List<OtherObject>`.

This is how I am doing,

```
List<MyObject> myList = returnsList();
List<OtherObj> emptyList = new ArrayList();

for(MyObject obj: myList) {   
    OtherObj oo = new OtherObj();
    oo.setUserName(obj.getName());
    oo.setUserAge(obj.getMaxAge());   
    emptyList.add(oo);  
}
```

I'm looking for a `lamdba` expression to do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you define constructor `OtherObj(String name, Integer maxAge)` you can do it this java8 style:

```
myList.stream()
    .map(obj -> new OtherObj(obj.getName(), obj.getMaxAge()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will map all objects in list `myList` to `OtherObj` and collect it to new `List` containing these objects.

Comment: Thanks ByeBYe. But what if I don't have access to modify the OtherObj?

Comment: You can do something like this:`.map(obj -> {
   final OtherObj obj2 = new OtherObj();
   obj2.setName(obj.getName());
          obj2.setMaxAge(obj.getMaxAge());
   return po;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a constructor in `OtherObject` which uses `MyObject` attributes,

```
public OtherObject(MyObject myObj) {
   this.username = myObj.getName();
   this.userAge = myObj.getAge();
}
```

and you can do following to create `OtherObject`s from `MyObject`s,

```
myObjs.stream().map(OtherObject::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that this is quite old post. However, this is my take on this based on the previous answers. The only modification in my answer is usage of `.collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add,ArrayList:addAll)`.

Sample code :

```
List<OtherObj> emptyList = myList.stream()
.map(obj -> {   
OtherObj oo = new OtherObj();
oo.setUserName(obj.getName());
oo.setUserAge(obj.getMaxAge());   
return oo; })
.collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add,ArrayList::addAll);
```